# Laravel with custom https domain on heroku not generating https routes

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, heroku

I have a Laravel 5.2 app running on heroku with a custom domain handled by Cloudflare. The custom domain uses a CNAME to point it to the heroku domain. I have enabled full ssl on Cloudflare to allow for https. The heroku url itself has ssl enabled so this is no problem.

When a route is generated (e.g. via something like `route('home')` it included the whole of the custom domain but with `http` rather than `https`. This often results in browser console warning like so:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over a
>   secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure
>   endpoint 'http://example.com/endpoint'. This endpoint should be made
>   available over a secure connection.

Any ideas why the Laravel route generator is not using https?

Answer (score 0):

in your `.env` file, ensure that your `APP_URL` is showing the https

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I was under the impression the `app.url` config value was only used for artisan commands. An ideal solution would just be to generate the routes without the domain part. E.g. `/endpoint` rather than `http://example.com/endpoint`

Comment: Ah, have a look at the following link, there is an answer there that includes `URL::forceSchema('https');`. You could put this in your `AppServiceProvider`.  http://laravel.io/forum/12-26-2014-routing-with-https

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the route to serve as `https`:

```
Route::get('signin', ['uses' => 'AuthController@sign', 'https']);
```

Make sure you haven't any asset hardcoded.

Comment: This wouldn't be a good solutions as 1) I'd have to manually update every route in the routes file. 2) My dev environment is not https so this would cause problems in development. The app should be able to detect whether ssl is enabled or not. I feel this problem is due to the way that I'm using cloudflare ssl with herouku. But it's still https end to end.

Comment: Use instead `env('https')`, then in your `.env` add `HTTPS=https` or 'HTTPS=http'.

Answer (score 0):

Late submission here but for me this worked. You can specify if routes should be HTTP or HTTPS by implicitly specifying by adding

`URL::forceScheme('https');`

At the bottom of your web.php or api.php file. URL is implemented in :

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

> I have tested it on Laravel 8.xx and it works the routes always generate HTTPS routes. You just have to do a little digging through the Laravel/framework repo on Github to [find many features](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/735) that don't have an official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who hasn't solved this yet, try doing this:

on your `config/app.php` edit the value of these:

```php
return [
  //...

  'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://yourdomainexample.herokuapp.com'),
  'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'https://yourdomainexample.herokuapp.com'),
]
```